# Accidentally deleted my wifi device wlan0

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, wlan

I was trying to fix my wifi on Kali Linux the other day and was following some tutorial. That didn't work, so I read somewhere that if I run this command

```
iw dev wlan0 del
```

After that command I can't seem to find my wlan device. When I type `iwconfig` it shows this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Anyone know what should I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to just reboot. The type of configuration change you've made does not persist across reboots.

Comment: do `sudo service network-manager restart`. It will reinitalise all the network interfaces...

Comment: that might work, if you have network-manager installed, and if network-manager knows how to recreate the necessary device. That's not a given.

Answer (score 10):

To undo deletion of wlan0, you can recreate it like so:

```
iw phy phy0 interface add wlan0 type managed
```

This is much faster than rebooting and more reliable than restarting network-manager.